# Antlr4 parser not handling custom token types

Tags: antlr4

I am migrating my grammar from version 3 to 4.  I recognize that version 4 has listeners and visitors and I plan to use them, but hope to do the migration piece meal.  I want to leave actions intact in my grammar for the time being.
I am using a custom token, and specify it using TokenLabelType in the option section of the grammar.  However, the generated code uses a 'match()' method which doesn't get promoted to my custom token, causing the java compilation to fail.
I also noticed the 'start' property of a token is not promoted to the custom token type either.
Is there something else I should do to properly use custom tokens in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, Ter posted a design document on the Antlr.org site that outlines the differences between Antlr3 and 4 (cannot seem to find it at the moment).

In any case, make sure your custom token extends `org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonToken`.  The supported Antlr4 Action attributes are listed [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Actions+and+Attributes).  The `start` attribute is valid on a parser rule, but not on a token.

Note also that many of the token fields, including start, are protected.  There are, however, corresponding getters defined in CommonToken -- `start` accessed by `getStartIndex()`.